# caching a large list in a cakephp model

Tags: php, caching, cakephp

I have a large array that I have implemented as a 'Vendor' file. I load the file in the controller using

> App::import('Vendor', 'constants_helper');

This works well.

However, I need to use this array in another model. Within the model I have

```
App::import('Vendor', 'constants_helper');
class MyModel extends AppModel {


    function afterFind($results) {
        if (!isset($constantsHelper)) {
            $constantsHelper = new ConstantsHelper();
        }

        $constantsHelper = new ConstantsHelper();
        $list= $constantsHelper->mylist;
 }
}
```

This seems to load the list. However I have 2 questions

**1. Is this the cakey (right) way to load the list ? 
 2. How can I cache this list , I dont want it reloaded for every model
    invocation.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call it a helper, because in cake, a helper is a view extension. I don't know the structure of the file, but maybe you can import that into a table in the db; or just define an array in the model, depends on how you want to use it in your app (just in that afterFind method, or also somewhere else?). And how big is it exactly? a few MB?